# How to get a chart similar to the reputation chart on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

I am always fascinated by the nice Reputation graph on my profile page here. I wanted to have one similar elsewhere. May I know what I may look at for this? I know this is more of a charting question on StackOverflow, but as it is about SO, thought of posting it here.

Comment: Which reputation graph? There are several ones on the profile page (and subtabs)